# Access iframe elements after refresh

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, peoplesoft

I am trying to extract data from a school peoplesoft portal page with an iframe element. 
On the Homepage, the page source has the iframe element. When I click on a button to leave that page(i.e. search classes) the page source stays the same but the elements on the page are different(observed using inspect element). 
I can access elements on the homepage, but not any of the others because I don't think I take into account the reloading of data/injection of other elements in the iframe. How can I access the elements post reload?
this is the snippet i'm using to access elements:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("id of iframe");
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var element = innerDoc.getElementById("name of id desired in iframe");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because upon navigating, the `document` of the iframe changes, and your `innerDoc` variable stores the value of the old document, You can create a function in order to retrieve the document instead of storing it in a static variable:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("id of iframe");
function getInnerDoc() {
    return iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
};
var element = getInnerDoc().getElementById("name of id desired in iframe");
```

As per your comments, it seems that the whole iframe gets stored in the variable and never refreshes, you should create a function in order to get the iframe document each time you need to retrieve an element:

```
function getIframeDocument(iframeId) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    return iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
};
var element = getIframeDocument().getElementById("name of id desired in iframe");
```

Comment: This works for the second page(the one after the main page), but not for ones following that page i.e.
I tried doing running getElementsByClassName as well for elements that had the same class on the second and third pages, and the method ends up being the same for both(even though they are actually different)

Comment: This goes the same for getElementById- if page 2 and 3 both had that id but are different values on each page, running the function on page 3 will return the same value as page2